# How Can I Unwrap an Array of Promises within a Chain of Array Methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, method-chaining

I have a chain of several maps, one of which needs to perform a database operation for each array element, so I'm using async await.

```
const resultsAsPromises = arr
  .map(syncDouble)
  .map(asyncMapper)
```

This isn't a problem if it is the last item in the chain because I can unwrap it with `Promise.all`

```
console.log('results', await Promise.all(resultsAsPromises))
```

However, there are other synchronous operations I need to perform afterward, so I'd like to have the promises' values unwrapped before moving on to the next `.map`.

Is there a way to do this? I thought perhaps just making an extraction mapper like

```
function extractPromiseValues(value) {
  return value.then(v => v);
}
```

would work, but alas, no.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
function timeout(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve(`number is ${i}`);
    }, 1);
  });
}

function syncDouble(i) {
  return i * 2;
}

async function asyncMapper(i) {
  return await timeout(i)
}

function extractPromiseValues(value) {
  return value.then(v => v);
}
async function main() {
  const resultsAsPromises = arr
    .map(syncDouble)
    .map(asyncMapper)
//     .map(extractPromiseValues)
  console.log('results', await Promise.all(resultsAsPromises))
}

main();
```

#### How can I unwrap an array of promises within a chain of array methods

Comment: `.then(v => v)` is essentially a no-op (other than adding another microtick of delay to each promise resolution).

Comment: I think the question is about the possibility of having a chain of `.map()` calls where, at some point, one returns an array of promises, and the next one returns an array of values that resolved from those promises. In that case, I'm not sure the answer below addresses that. Thoughts?

Comment: Meaning, is `arr.map(returnValAfter1sec).map(doubleValAfterThat)` possible as written? (where `returnValAfter1sec` takes a value and returns a promise, and `doubleValAfterThat` takes a promise and returns a value).

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I believe my edit has addressed your interpretation. Would you agree?

Comment: I am thinking uses `Array.reduce` may be one solution because the forth parameter of its callback is the array itself.

So inside the callback, we can use `Promise.all` for resolve all promises.

Comment: @Sphinx no you can't, because the return value of the `.reduce()` method would still be a promise. You'd have to insert an `await` preceding that section of the chain regardless of your approach.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts many thanks, it does address it now, I was thinking and writing a solution in that direction and I realized that, like you said, there is no avoiding wrapping the asynchronous part of the chain with `(await <asyncPart>)<syncPart>`.

Comment: I'm guessing you'd really like a solution that allows you to stack up as many `.map(somethingSynchronous)` and `.map(somethingAsynchronous)` mappings as you choose, in any order. It's kind of possible but you need to make sure that (a) the functions are compatible with each other (that each returns a data type that the next function will accept) and (b) that the "synchronous" functions are written asynchronously (or promisified).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yeah that is definitely the idea. Throwing a `.filter` into the mix really failed quite miserably as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than passing an identity function to `.then()`, pass your synchronous operation instead, OR `await` the promise in an `async` function before passing it to your synchronous operation:

```
function syncCapitalize(s) {
  return s.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
}

const resultsAsPromises = arr
  .map(syncDouble)
  .map(asyncMapper)
  .map(p => p.then(syncCapitalize)); // OR
//.map(async p => syncCapitalize(await p));
```

In the context of your example, this would look like:

```js
function timeout(i) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`number is ${i}`);
    }, 1);
  });
}

function syncDouble(i) {
  return i * 2;
}

function asyncMapper(i) {
  return timeout(i);
}

function syncCapitalize(s) {
  return s.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
}

async function main() {
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const resultsAsPromises = arr
    .map(syncDouble)
    .map(asyncMapper)
    .map(p => p.then(syncCapitalize)); // OR
  //.map(async p => syncCapitalize(await p));

  console.log('results', await Promise.all(resultsAsPromises));
}

main();
```

Alternatively, if we are interpreting the question as [Ghassen Louhaichi has](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62939432#comment111302820_62939432), you could use the [TC39 pipeline operator (`|>`) proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator) to write the chain using one of the options below:

#### [F# Pipelines Proposal](https://github.com/valtech-nyc/proposal-fsharp-pipelines#use-with-await)

```
const results = arr
  .map(syncDouble)
  .map(asyncMapper)
  |> Promise.all
  |> await
  .map(syncCapitalize);
```

#### [Smart Pipelines Proposal](https://github.com/js-choi/proposal-smart-pipelines#smart-pipelines)

```
const results = (arr
  .map(syncDouble)
  .map(asyncMapper)
  |> await Promise.all(#))
  .map(syncCapitalize);
```

Unfortunately, unless you are using a [Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator), or until one of these proposals is merged into the official ECMAScript specification, you have to wrap the chain with `await Promise.all(...)`:

```
const results = (await Promise.all(arr
  .map(syncDouble)
  .map(asyncMapper)))
  .map(syncCapitalize);
```

Finally, in the context of your full example:

```js
function timeout(i) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`number is ${i}`);
    }, 1);
  });
}

function syncDouble(i) {
  return i * 2;
}

function asyncMapper(i) {
  return timeout(i);
}

function syncCapitalize(s) {
  return s.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
}

async function main() {
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const results = (await Promise.all(arr
    .map(syncDouble)
    .map(asyncMapper)))
    .map(syncCapitalize);

  console.log('results', results);
}

main();
```

Comment: Exquisite! Can we vote on these proposals somewhere?

Comment: And just to be pedantic, at the end of your last snippet, all you need is `console.log('results', resultsAsPromises);`, because the results are not promises anymore, in fact, the name of  the array is misleading.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi there's no place to "vote" per se, but a lot of active debate goes on in the [GitHub issues section](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator/issues) to address use-cases, syntax, semantics, implementation details, etc. Generally speaking, the more attention one style gets, the more likely it will be chosen by the committee over the other. Just make sure you don't post superfluous issues for the sake of gaining attention though.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi right thanks, I missed that. Copy-paste error.

Comment: I think this is really good. `.map(p => p.then(syncCapitalize))` is just what I was looking for! I will have to dig in a little bit to understand this proposal. Wrapping in `Promise.all` is also not bad at all, maybe like on extra step to follow, but good nonetheless. Thanks very much Patrick.